# How to filter the pandas dataframe when one cell value of all columns equals to a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with around 20-30 columns. I would like to filter for all the rows when one cell value in that rows equals to "Fail".

The dataframe would look like this:

```
    Column_1 Column_2 ... Column_30
0      Pass   Pass          Fail
1      Pass   Pass          Pass
2      Fail   Pass          Pass
3      Pass   Pass          Pass
4      Pass   Pass          Pass
..
```

I would like to have row 0 and 2 filter out. Is there any way to achieve that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `any`

```
out = df[~df.eq('Fail').any(1)]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the amazing solution using ```any```. Just one quick follow-up question: is there anyway we could grab the column names whenever there is a ```Fail``` in that record?

Comment: @SkipperLin you want to have by row ?

Comment: yes technically. In my original dataset, I would love to obtain the column names that contain a Fail in a list format (i.e., [Column 1, Column 30])

Comment: @SkipperLin s = df.eq('Fail').any() ; s[s].index